# trying to establish a DB server in AWS... what do I have to look for?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, server, backend

I'm trying to make a DB server for indie game with AWS. But since it's the first time I'm doing anything with a server, and being an amateur programmer(started like last year) I'm stuck with no progress at all for almost a month :(

It'll only need to hold data(id, clients' shopping records, etc.), and clients will not access to this directly - only loaded/added via separate app.

for now I just need to check whether I can control the DB - check if I can have access to server by app or wherever.

Looks like I need to use API...? I still have no basic clue on where I should I start on :(

for now I made an EC2 instance, and a base DB from RDS(no tables but will fill that up as I go on), trying to practice API as written in amazon docs but not going so well... ㅠㅠ

Could anyone give any advise on what I'm supposed to look at if I'm to establish this server? I tried searching here and there for quite a while but I'm still lost and now getting really desperate :( any links to simple guide is also greatly welcomed.

Thank you in advance.

current situation:

- I had my DB instance at RDS(planning to use MySql)
- I have EC2 instance up but it's blank - really dont know how to use it :(
- I plan to get this up and running via python flask(ppl recommended this if I'm going to use python)
- My DB is in VPC i think(i made the instance from AWS RDS dashboard)

Comment: You need to be more clear :
1) Is the Db instance RDS or EC2 ?
2) From where do you want to establish connection , local machine , code on ec2 or somewhere else ?
3) Is th DB in VPC ? Or did you choose default db ?

Comment: um.... 1) DB instance is at RDS atm(planning to use MySql). EC2 i just have blank instance there - still have no idea what I'm supposed to do with it. 

2) I really didnt' understood the question - if you're asking what kind of app, it'll be mobile app(this is a DB server for mobile games). Or what am I going to use to run this with? - I am planning to use Python flask for actual running. since I was stuck on what am I supposed to do really havent done anything on this yet. 

3) since I made the DB instance at the AWS RDS dashboard, I guess it's a VPC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd agree with the people that have recommended Flask for backend Python development. Django is another alternative.

This is quite a broad question but it sounds to me like you just need to focus on getting a Flask environment on your EC2 instance so this can consume your MySQL database.

Here's a guide on deploying Flask apps to AWS RDS.

https://medium.com/@rodkey/deploying-a-flask-application-on-aws-a72daba6bb80

Just apply the Flask installation to your EC2 instance, which you can access by using SSH and the keypair you configured when building the instance.

Comment: thanks for the answer. it didnt work tho :S kept getting error when making EB instance.